# Arrays.binarySearch throws exception in an array of different types of Objects?

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

Q. why line 2 & line 4 dont give exception while line 1, line 3 do??

```
Object arr[]={1,2,5,"ABC",6};
Arrays.sort(arr);//line 1
Arrays.binarySearch(arr,5);//line 2
Arrays.binarySearch(arr,"ABC");//line 3
Arrays.binarySearch(arr,6);//line 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with if the `binarySearch()` method actually tries to compare two incomparable objects.

On line 2 and 4, you are lucky enough to find the element you are searching for without running into an incompatible object, and no `ClassCastException` is thrown.

Actually, with your edit (the array was `{1,2,5,"ABC",6}` before), line 2 is the only one working.

Answer (score 1):

From [`Arrays#sort` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) (emphasys mine):

> Throws:
>
> IllegalArgumentException - if fromIndex > toIndex or (optional) if the natural ordering of the array elements is found to violate the Comparable contract
>
> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - if fromIndex < 0 or toIndex > a.length
>
> **ClassCastException - if the array contains elements that are not mutually comparable (for example, strings and integers).**

From [`Arrays#binarySearch` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29) (emphasys mine):

> Throws
>
> ClassCastException - if the search key **is not comparable** to the elements of the array.

Note that in lines 1 and 3 of your code, `"ABC"` nor `"6"` are comparable with 1, 2 or 5.